# How can I style a tooltip for an NVD3 Chart?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

Referencing the NVD3 framework. I'm trying to add a customized tooltip for the following pie chart listed below:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['nvd3']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.options = {
        chart: {
            type: 'pieChart',
            height: 500,
            x: function(d){return d.key;},
            y: function(d){return d.y;},
            color:['#CE1B1F', '#FFC455', '#00A6CD'],
            showLabels: false,
            duration: 500,
            labelThreshold: 0.01,
            labelSunbeamLayout: true,
            legend: {
                margin: {
                    top: 5,
                    right: 35,
                    bottom: 5,
                    left: 0
                }
            }
        }
    };

    $scope.data = [
        {
            key: "A",
            y: 2
        },
        {
            key: "B",
            y: 1
        },
        {
            key: "C",
            y: 3
        },
    ];
});
```

Since I'm just working with the example from Krispo's [github][1] I'm not sure how I can customize a tooltip so that it resembles the following:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to add custom tool-tip, you need to add `tooltip` to existing nvd3 options like this:

```
tooltip: {
     contentGenerator: function (e) {
           //Create and return desired tool-tip as html using e.series and e.data
     }
}
```

If you need to use some additional values or attributes for each of your series you can define them like this in $scope.data:

```
$scope.data = [
        {
            key: "CAT I",
            y: 2,
            MyAttribute1:"DLA Avn ... CAT I",
            MyAttribute2:"DLA Energy ... CAT I"
        },
        {
            key: "CAT II",
            y: 3,
            MyAttribute1:"DLA Avn ... CAT II",
            MyAttribute2:"DLA Energy ... CAT II"
        },
        {
            key: "CAT III",
            y: 1,
            MyAttribute1:"DLA Avn ... CAT III",
            MyAttribute2:"DLA Energy ... CAT III"
        },
    ];
```

now you can access custom values inside tool-tip function using `e.data` like this:

```
tooltip: {
         contentGenerator: function (e) {
              var series = e.series[0];
              if (series.value === null) return;

              var rows = 
                "<tr>" +
                  "<td class='key'>" + series.key + '- #3: ' + "</td>" +
                  "<td class='x-value'>" + e.data.MyAttribute1 + "</td>" + 
                "</tr>" +
                "<tr>" +
                  "<td class='key'>" + series.key + '- #5: ' + "</td>" +
                  "<td class='x-value'>" + e.data.MyAttribute2 + "</td>" + 
                "</tr>";

              var header = 
                "<thead>" + 
                  "<tr>" +
                    "<td class='legend-color-guide'><div style='background-color: " + series.color + ";'></div></td>" +
                    "<td class='key'><strong>" + series.key + "</strong></td>" +
                  "</tr>" + 
                "</thead>";

              return "<table>" +
                  header +
                  "<tbody>" + 
                    rows + 
                  "</tbody>" +
                "</table>";
            } 
}
```

There is an **[Edited Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QzU2cIYkhGy0Ij5ORbsz?p=preview)** to show you how this can be done.

hope that helps.

Comment: this absolutely was what I was looking for. For my understanding, could you explain how the information is being passed into the function parameter 'e'?

Comment: @KunalOjha ,when mouse hovers any seri , nvd3 pass'es the seri information and data of that seri as e.series[0] and e.data, e.series[0] contains key,value and color of that seri, and e.data contains any value or attribute that you've set in nvd3 data.

Comment: by seri you referring to each individual wedge of the pie chart?

Comment: @KunalOjha ,exactly

Comment: @hsh please can you help answer this question is it nvd3 related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40709470/how-to-use-dynamic-csv-data-for-visualisation-with-nvd3-and-angular2

Comment: @hsh can you redact or remove the plunkr pls?